# Using cmd module: how to have sub-commands documented in `help` and integrated with autocomplete?

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, subcommand

I'm using the `cmd` module and have a command called `server` (method `do_server()`) which has autocomplete out of the box (I'm on macOS). That's all fine and works like expected. But if i want to additionally also use a sub-command on the `server` command, things don't work out like i need it.

I would need the following:
- sub-commands should also be integrated with the `help` command (shouldn't be shown when entering `help` since they are not first level commands but should be shown when entering `help server`)
- sub-commands should also integrate with auto-complete

Currently i don't see a way to define sub-commands out-of-the-box. I need to implement them as arguments for a command which isn't ideal.

My question would be, how can i achieve automatic documentation of the sub-commands with `help` and have autocomplete so that it integrates as good as possible with `cmd`?

For this example, i'd like to better integrate `connect` as a sub-command:

```py
from cmd import Cmd


class Tansanit(Cmd):

    def do_server(self, args):
        """ Show server info """
        print("Some server details")

        if args and args == "connect":
            print("Connect to the server")

    def do_quit(self, args):
        """ Quit CLI """
        raise SystemExit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Tansanit()
    t.prompt = "> "
    t.cmdloop()
```

I would prefer to have something like this:

```py
from cmd import Cmd


class Tansanit(Cmd):

    def do_server(self, args):
        """ Show server info """
        print("Some server details")

    def do_server_connect(self, args):
        """ Connect to server """
        print("Connect to the server")

    def do_quit(self, args):
        """ Quit CLI """
        raise SystemExit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Tansanit()
    t.prompt = "> "
    t.cmdloop()
```

Unfortunately that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relavant infos can be found [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CmdModule)

### Autocomplete for sub-commands

> The interpreter is able to process completion for commands names, but for commands arguments you will have to help it. For the command xxx, this is done by defining a complete_xxx method. For example, if you have defined a color command, the completion method for this command could be:

```
_AVAILABLE_COLORS = ('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red', 'black')
def complete_color(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
    return [i for i in _AVAILABLE_COLORS if i.startswith(text)]
```

> The complete_xxx method takes four arguments:
>
> text is the string we are matching against, all returned matches must begin with it
>   line is is the current input line
>   begidx is the beginning index in the line of the text being matched
>   endidx is the end index in the line of the text being matched
>   It should return a list (possibly empty) of strings representing the possible completions. The arguments begidx and endidx are useful when completion depends on the position of the argument.

### `help` for sub-commands

> You can also define help for topics that are not related to commands:

```
def help_introduction(self):
    print 'introduction'
    print 'a good place for a tutorial'
```

This isn't perfect since the help will be categorized as `undocumented commands` but it's for an argument. But maybe still better then nothing.